# d3 time scale add before and after time range a percentage of time interval

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using time.scale.domain of d3 to render some graphs. e.g.

```
var time_range=d3.time.scale().domain([new Date(2008, 1, 1), new Date(2015, 11, 10)]);
```

How can I add +- 10% of time range to it ?

```
function add_percentage(start_date, end_date , percentage){
    //Add 2015 - 2008 => Around 7 years , if percentage = 10 => around 9-10 months before and after 
}
add_percentage(new Date(2008, 1, 1),new Date(2015, 11, 10),10)
//Should return around 9-10 months before and after.
```

Comment: Try `d3.time.scale().domain(...).nice()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by using the code below. I think it would be best if you worked on the difference between days and not just months, as this would give you more accuracy. But since you are using percents, I don't really think that accuracy of that much importance at this stage.

```
function add_percentage(s, e , percentage){
    var t2 = e.getTime();
    var t1 = s.getTime();

    diff= parseInt((t2-t1)/(24*3600*1000))*percentage/100;
    d1=new Date(s.getFullYear(),s.getMonth(),s.getDay()-diff);
    d2=new Date(e.getFullYear(),e.getMonth(),e.getDay()+diff);
    return {start:d1, end:d2}
}
```

Is this helping you?